# How to receive the ASPN Token in Xamarin Forms iOS-App

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, azure-notificationhub

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-backend-service-xamarin-forms) tutorial to implement Push-Notifications in my Xamarin-Forms App (especially the iOS part). Now my problem is, when I press the register-button, I get the error message "Unable to resolve token for APNS".
Stepping through the code in debug mode I could verify, that the Token property in DeviceInstallationService is indeed *null*.
So I've gone one step back, and identified that the Token is set only via RegisteredForRemoteNotification in AppDelegate.cs, but this method is never called when I run the App.

Here is some code: **App-Delegate**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Foundation;
using Notes.iOS.Extensions;
using Notes.iOS.Services;
using Notes.Services;
using UIKit;
using UserNotifications;
using Xamarin.Essentials;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using Syncfusion.SfCalendar.XForms.iOS;

namespace Notes.iOS
{
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        IPushDemoNotificationActionService _notificationActionService;
        INotificationRegistrationService _notificationRegistrationService;
        IDeviceInstallationService _deviceInstallationService;

        IPushDemoNotificationActionService NotificationActionService
            => _notificationActionService ??
                (_notificationActionService =
                ServiceContainer.Resolve<IPushDemoNotificationActionService>());

        INotificationRegistrationService NotificationRegistrationService
            => _notificationRegistrationService ??
                (_notificationRegistrationService =
                ServiceContainer.Resolve<INotificationRegistrationService>());

        IDeviceInstallationService DeviceInstallationService
            => _deviceInstallationService ??
                (_deviceInstallationService =
                ServiceContainer.Resolve<IDeviceInstallationService>());

        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            Bootstrap.Begin(() => new DeviceInstallationService());
            if (DeviceInstallationService.NotificationsSupported)
            {
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(
                    UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert |
                    UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge |
                    UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound,
                    (approvalGranted, error) =>
                    {
                        if (approvalGranted && error == null)
                            RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
                    });
            }
            LoadApplication(new App());
            using (var userInfo = options?.ObjectForKey(
                UIApplication.LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey) as NSDictionary)
                ProcessNotificationActions(userInfo);
            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }

        void RegisterForRemoteNotifications()
        {
            MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                var pushSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(
                    UIUserNotificationType.Alert |
                    UIUserNotificationType.Badge |
                    UIUserNotificationType.Sound,
                    new NSSet());

                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(pushSettings);
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
            });
        }

        Task CompleteRegistrationAsync(NSData deviceToken)
        {
            DeviceInstallationService.Token = deviceToken.ToHexString();
            return NotificationRegistrationService.RefreshRegistrationAsync();
        }

        void ProcessNotificationActions(NSDictionary userInfo)
        {
            if (userInfo == null)
                return;

            try
            {
                var actionValue = userInfo.ObjectForKey(new NSString("action")) as NSString;

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(actionValue?.Description))
                    NotificationActionService.TriggerAction(actionValue.Description);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
            => CompleteRegistrationAsync(deviceToken).ContinueWith((task)
                => { if (task.IsFaulted) throw task.Exception; });

        public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(
            UIApplication application,
            NSDictionary userInfo)
            => ProcessNotificationActions(userInfo);

        public override void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(
            UIApplication application,
            NSError error)
            => Debug.WriteLine(error.Description);
    }
}
```

**DeviceInstallationService:**

```
﻿using System;
using Notes.Models;
using Notes.Services;
using UIKit;

namespace Notes.iOS.Services
{
    public class DeviceInstallationService : IDeviceInstallationService
    {
        const int SupportedVersionMajor = 13;
        const int SupportedVersionMinor = 0;
        public string Token { get; set; }

        public bool NotificationsSupported
            => UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(SupportedVersionMajor, SupportedVersionMinor);

        public string GetDeviceId()
            => UIDevice.CurrentDevice.IdentifierForVendor.ToString();

        public DeviceInstallation GetDeviceInstallation(params string[] tags)
        {
            if (!NotificationsSupported)
                throw new Exception(GetNotificationsSupportError());

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Token))
                throw new Exception("Unable to resolve token for APNS");

            var installation = new DeviceInstallation
            {
                InstallationId = GetDeviceId(),
                Platform = "apns",
                PushChannel = Token
            };

            installation.Tags.AddRange(tags);

            return installation;
        }

        string GetNotificationsSupportError()
        {
            if (!NotificationsSupported)
                return $"This app only supports notifications on iOS {SupportedVersionMajor}.{SupportedVersionMinor} and above. You are running {UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemVersion}.";

            if (Token == null)
                return $"This app can support notifications but you must enable this in your settings.";


            return "An error occurred preventing the use of push notifications";
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see this is really 1:1 the example code, the only difference is that my project is called Notes.

I skipped the Firebase and Android-Part as I only need push-notifications for iOS so far and as far as I underestood these are not necessary for iOS only.

Thanks your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some points to check if `RegisteredForRemoteNotification` not called:

1. Open `Entitlements.plist` and ensure that `Enable Push Notifications` is checked when viewed in the `Entitlements` tab. Then, ensure the APS Environment setting is set to development when viewed in the Source tab.
2. Make sure that you are testing the remote-notification in a **real device** instead of a simulator. A simulator does not support remote-notification.
3. Make sure that you agreed receiving notification permission.
4. Make sure the certification you use has enabled the push notification ability.

Refer: [configuring-the-remote-notifications-environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications?tabs=macos#configuring-the-remote-notifications-environment)

Comment: Thanks for your help! The problem was, that I tried the app on a simulator device. Using a real device fixed it.

Comment: @SebSeb Can you please accept the answer(click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Comment: Same problem here: simulator crashes with same error, but real device works. Bu now the App Store team rejects our app because of the crash. How did you get your app in the store? Or is there a way we can fix the registration?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the message returned from the following function in your App Delegate `AppDelegate.cs`

```
public override void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(
    UIApplication application, 
    NSError error)
```

For instance

> no valid “aps-environment” entitlement string found for application